# onclick does not call function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When I run the following code, the alert messages shows up but `this.test()` does not run:

```
function SomeFunction() {
    document.onclick = function(e) {
        alert("Hi");
        this.test();
    };
}

SomeFunction.prototype.test = function (){
    ...
}
```

However when I try this:

```
function SomeFunction() {
    document.onclick = this.test();
}

SomeFunction.prototype.test = function (){
    ...
}
```

`this.test()` will run.

EDIT: I have added more details to my code.

Comment: Your browser version and is there any error message from browser console window?

Comment: When you set a breakpoint in the function, and check the value of `this`, what does it say? Isn't that the obvious thing to do when debugging something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to scope. Try:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    alert("Hi");
    test();
};
```

`this` will vary depending upon where it is called from.  In your first example, you are calling it from within an anonymous function and therefore the scope of `this` shifts to inside that function. In the second example, the scope is a level higher and refers to your `SomeFunction()` function.

Since your function is nested inside another function, you may want to reassign `this` to a another variable that is accessible up the scope chain. E.g.

```
function SomeFunction() {

    that = this;

    document.onclick = function(e) {
        alert("Hi");
        that.test();
    };
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but it doesn't work. This function and test() are in the same "class".

Comment: Can you post the whole class - another solution would be to define assign `this` to another variable and call if from there.

Comment: My that = this suggestion in my edited answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the word "this" refers to function itself. So the function test would be outside its scope.

But on the second one you are telling the code that this.test() is the actual onclick function, that is why it's working there and not on the first one.